# change column instead of row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to change column letter instead of row number; when i drag it down. I tried using below formula but it is no working.
eg =

```
B20=INDEX(pmp!$C$4:$K$4;0;ZEILE(pmp!C$4:C4))

B21=INDEX(pmp!$C$4:$K$4;0;ZEILE(pmp!C$4:C5))
```

when I drag down it is showing me the same output as in cell B20

same for using v lookup

```
C20=SVERWEIS(ProjectMonths;Design!B200:W204;10;1)

C21=SVERWEIS(ProjectMonths;Design!B200:W204;11;1)
```

I drag it down its changes the Reference but it does not change column no from 10 to 11

Comment: *I drag it down* that's the default Excel behaviour. It will change row relative references when dragging **up/down** and column relative references when dragging **left/right**. You'll need a formula to calculate the column number.

Comment: Maybe B20=INDEX(pmp!$C$4:$K$4;0;ZEILE(pmp!4:4)) and C20=SVERWEIS(ProjectMonths;Design!$B$200:$W$204;ZEILE(Design!10:10);0) then drag down

Comment: @bosco_yip works fine